# WordPress Theme development: The new CSS code I'm writing not being applied

Tags: css, wordpress, xampp, localhost, wordpress-theming

I have a localhost WordPress installation with XAMPP (v3.3.0), **PHP 7.4.33, Apache 2.4.54 and MySql 15.1 Distrib 10.4.27-MariaDB   **

I'm learning how to build themes.
First, I began with Local by Flywheel and Nginx server, but it was very slow when I refresh the browser for new code changes .. after a while trying new stuff here and there for my new school project, I made a decision to move to XAMPP and it was faster, but my CSS new code changes don't apply even when restarting apache and MySQL, So I wonder why is that happening.

**The CSS Files are loading from *function.php* very normally otherwise nothing will appear in the browser right ! **

`

```
/********************** */
/** LOAD CSS FILE(S) */
/********************** */
function load_stylesheets()
{
    wp_enqueue_style('custom_google_fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Aref+Ruqaa&family=Rubik:wght@300;500;700&display=swap');
    /** Loading CSS Files */
    wp_enqueue_style('general', get_theme_file_uri('/css/general.css')); 
    wp_enqueue_style('main_section', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main_section.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_style('interior-pages', get_theme_file_uri('/css/interior-pages.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style('blog-style', get_theme_file_uri('/css/blog-style.css'));
    /** Responsive css */
    wp_enqueue_style('queries', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/queries.css'); 
    

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');
```

`
But any other new lines (or small changes) on my CSS code won't be applied.

I tried to Override the CSS files by local files in the DevTools > sources in Microsoft edge browser but in chrome I didn't know how to do it..

Comment: Add versions numbers, and update them, so that your browser knows to fetch a new version

Comment: basically `wp_enqueue_style('blog-style', get_theme_file_uri('/css/blog-style.css'), "", "1.0" )`

Comment: Know it does not help, when inspect the CSS files in the browser it shows me the wrong files, so the oldest version of my code is loading but the newest changes doesn't load

Answer (score 0):

[Update]:

- The best solution I found (thanks to your hints about the cache thing), which is to add the microtime() function in the version parameter in the specific wp_enqueue_style() that I don't want the browser to cache it for me, just like this

wp_enqueue_style('general', get_theme_file_uri('/css/general.css'), NULL, microtime()).

So, then the other files that I don't need to change it keeps the cache and load faster, you can see the effects of this in the DevTools > Network < (CSS)